# how to convert Csv file to libsvm using python and pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, libsvm

I had one csv file and i needed to convert it to libsvm format so i wrote a python script to make the required changes . Now the matrix i have in python is in the libsvm form but how to write it to libsvm format . But now how to save it in file.libsvm ?

pandas module has data.to_csv snd csv module has csv writer . 
is there any way i can save it in libsvm format . I am thinking of saving it as txt file then i'll rename it . Don't know will it work it or not . 
I read the data using 
data=pd.read_csv('abc.csv',header=None,index_col=False)
and made the required changes . so now data has the file to be saved .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into [phraug](https://github.com/zygmuntz/phraug), it has been made for this purpose.